# Alternative for LogManager.setRepositorySelector() from log4j 1.2.17 in log4j 2.16.0

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am converting an application from log4j 1.2.17 to 2.16.0 and it seems like in log4j2 there is no longer the setRepositorySelector() method in LogManager. I cannot use the log 1.x bridge as is because the project does not meet the requirements listed in the migration documentation.

Is there any log4j2 workaround for the functionality below? I did not write the original code, I am just updating it.

```
        //The "guard" is a simple object that protects against re-setting of the
        //LoggerFactory by anyone but the one who set it first with a particular
        //"guard".  Basically, this would allow a container to set the LoggerFactory,
        //but disallow applications running in the container from changing it.  If
        //the container holds a handle on the "guard" object, then it alone can
        //change the LoggerFactory.  If no one holds a handle on the "guard" object,
        //then no one can change the LoggerFactory once it is set the first time.       
        Object guard = new Object();
        try {
            LogManager.setRepositorySelector(new ContextJNDISelector(), guard);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception, " + CLASS_NAME + ".contextInitialized(): " + e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Log4j 2.x API can have multiple implementations the `RepositorySelector` has been renamed to `ContextSelector` and moved to [`Log4jContextFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/Log4jContextFactory.html). Therefore you need to use:

```java
LogManager.setFactory(new Log4jContextFactory(new JndiContextSelector()));
```

**Remark:** The code above must be called **before** any (direct or indirect) call to `LogManager.getLogger` or similar methods.